# What was the writer going for with '酗逼'?

Tags: meaning

Started reading this article this morning: [为抢红包，小伙跳楼威逼母亲买iPhone6s](http://news.cnfol.com/it/20151016/21610292.shtml?t=1445048857070) but couldn't get past the first word:

> **酗逼**母亲买6s，为此不惜以跳楼威胁。

[emphasis is my own]

酗逼 appears again in the following sentence:

> 前几天媒体刚曝出马来西亚一女孩为买iPhone导致其母亲跪在大商场求其别买，没想到现在重庆也有一**酗逼**母亲买6s，因为他嫌iPhone4S抢红包速度太慢，无奈其母亲每月1000多元的退休金实在买不起，他就在家里闹着要跳楼，其父身在外地求助警察，后经警察劝解，他认识到自己错误，离开了要跳楼的窗台，主动向母亲道了歉，并保证以后不再作出这样冲动的举动。

I can't make heads nor tails of this word

A [baidu search](https://www.baidu.com/s?ie=utf-8&f=8&rsv_bp=1&rsv_idx=2&tn=baidutop10&wd=%22%E9%85%97%E9%80%BC%22&oq=%E9%85%97%E9%80%BC&rsv_pq=f0f19cd600033298&rsv_t=8e96gjYbCx5rM9ZrNG6rq3Jka4nMfmMS3urlLJX8GRrUXiTm%2BdAZQ41yKh%2Fq4JYd3Q&rsv_enter=1&inputT=1339&rsv_sug3=7&rsv_sug2=0&rsv_sug4=1956) only gives the same article back for using the *exact* word 酗逼, everything else just returns things like `酗酒逼...`

The article has nothing to do with liquor `酒` or the like.

I've got to guess it's a total mistake. Probably the author thought he was writing `xiong bi` and not `xu bi` anyway.

- What was the writer going for with '酗逼'?

Comment: 酗 is Pinyin typo for 小伙?

Comment: Perhaps it should read 需逼? Characters often slip like that.

Comment: http://yueyu.tongbu.com/86031.html Seems like NS.X. is correct.

Comment: http://www.cqtimes.cn/roll/20151014/78154.shtml These news website just keep copying each other...

Comment: 抢 means "to rob", does it have here a different meaning ?

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred 抢 also means 'rush; fight for front position'. 抢 in 抢红包 means to be the first few people who click the button and claim the money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally, 酗 means drinking alcohol and getting drunk, 逼，force someone to do sth. I saw this word in some Classical Chinese text, but I don't think people use this word regularly. So, I suspect this could be typo.

Comment: why is the meaning "drinking alcohol and getting drunk" ? could it also be used for "drinking alcohol without getting drunk " ? is it used only as a verb or as noun and adjective ?

Comment: This is a meaning from a Chinese dictionary, means drinking without control; bacchanal. This character regularly with 酒 alcohol.

Comment: perfect, we call it "komasaufen" in germany.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to pay more attention to 酗

酗 originally means drink to much, and act insane after drinking. So it has a meaning of too much/over and insane. 逼means force or heavily ask for. So 酗逼means over-force insane. As described in the topic, the young guy force parents to buy iPhone in a insane way